# Better way to import module from subdirectories at the same level

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following project structure 

`main
  - exp1
     - mod1.py
  - exp2
     - mod2.py`

I can import a module `abc` from mod2.py in mod1.py using the following

`from ..exp2.mod2 import abc`

Is there any other way of importing these modules where I do not have to use `..`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always import using the absolute module name

```
from main.exp2.mod2 import abc  
# or 
# from exp2.mod2 import abc
# (?)
```

for me this is the preferred way.

this way and yours are the only available options...

Comment: there's also manually adding dirs in `sys.path` (but that's ugly).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes, should have added 'aside from changing the PYTHONPATH' or something like that...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there is an easier way than using `'..'` unless you alter the project structure:

```
# mod1.py
    import sys
    sys.path.append('..')
    from exp2.mod2 import abc
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always set a PYTHONPATH and then import from that path as main.

In your case you should do the following,

```
export PYTHONPATH=main   (Full path of main dir in shell )
from exp2.mod2 import abc
```

If you do .. it is not a proper way also you will face some issue when you transfer the code or during the deployment time